# XmlDocument.InnerText Replacement for New .NET

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xmldocument

I am attempting to convert an object of type `XmlDocument` to a String.

In Visual Studio 2010 all that was required was to call `XmlDocument.InnerText` as per the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.100).aspx).

In the new .NET framework `XmlDocument.InnerText` has been discontinued, and now throws an exception as per the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx).

I would simply use `XmlDocument.InnerXml` as this returns a String, although the issue is that the string returned does not contain any of the xml document formatting (newlines, indentation, etc). The legacy `XmlDocument.InnerText` did return all of this.

It looks like `XmlDocument.InnerText` is still available for Nodes and `XmlElements`, although I'm wondering what the simplest way would be to get the entire `XmlDocument` as text.

Comment: What do you specifically mean by "new .NET framework"? .NET Framework 4.7.1? .NET Core 2.0? .NET Standard 2.0? .NET Standard 1.1?

Comment: @NightOwl888 Many of the newer versions don't support it, mainly I'm referring to " .NET Framework (current version) " in the Microsoft documentation.

Comment: Yes, it would be very helpful if you shared exactly what version you're using, although there are some easy answers, anyways...

Comment: Also, do you want to _always_ have line breaks and indenting for every xml - so they're always formatted "pretty".  Or do you want to only show the formatting of the source string, if they came from a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a StringWriter...

```
    ' build an XML document to test
    Dim x As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    With x
        .AppendLine("<root>")
        .AppendLine("<foo>bar</foo>")
        .AppendLine("</root>")
    End With
    Dim d As New XmlDocument
    d.LoadXml(x.ToString)

    ' create a stringwriter
    Dim sw As New System.IO.StringWriter

    ' write the xml to the stringwriter
    d.Save(sw)

    ' get the contents of the stringwriter with whitespace and line breaks preserved
    Debug.WriteLine(sw.ToString)
```